# What is the well-known mechanism to make sure the grounding connection always works?

Tags: safety

I want to put high-voltage machines or devices on potentially hazardous working places such as kitchens, washing areas, etc.

Is there any well-know mechanism to make sure the grounding connection always works? I meant, when the grounding cable is accidentally cut, current from the electric outlet cannot flow to the device automatically.

Comment: Normally, most people would employ a suitably qualified professional. This is not the sort of thing to tackle yourself, and may even be in conflict with local laws/regulations (depending on where you live).

Comment: The traditional answer is that you make it part of the same cable that carries the power to the appliance, and that's why 3-wire outlets were invented. The modern solution is to use GFCI/RCD devices, which work even without a ground connection. These are now required by law in new construction in most jurisdictions for the types of areas you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have ground fault monitoring relays that only activate the appliance when the voltage on all lines is within expected window. They can also make sure the phase sequence is correct.

These are specialty devices for industrial equipment. Often found in rental machinery since three phase motors switch direction if you change the phase sequence (swap two wires).

For residential use you can use [ground fault current interrupter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual-current_device) (gfci), also known as residual current detectors (rcd).
These devices fit in your breaker panel and trip when the current of live and neutral is not equal.
They interrupt current when you touch it and accidentally create a path to ground.

They mandatory in some parts of the world.